# In the optical bench experiment of two pins (the object and image pin) kept on either side of convex lens. Why the real image appears on the lens?

Tags: optics, lenses

Since real images can only be seen on screen why are we able to see it on the lens. Will it not be called virtual?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking through the lens, what you see is a virtual image.  Used as a simple magnifier, a convex lens lets you bring the object close to the lens giving it a large angular size, while putting the virtual image in focus out beyond your near point (and not “on the lens”). On an optical bench, a small light bulb and a screen work better than pins for locating a real object and image.

Comment: So, you are saying that during this experiment looking at the lens what we see on it is virtual image then why is the image upside down. Also concave mirror does the same thing. Please answer how lens itself shows the real image on it and not at the real intersection of rays in the experiment.

Comment: If you look at the lens from the same side as your real object, the “front” surface of the lens acts as a convex mirror.  Again you are seeing a virtual image which is located beyond the lens (as in the case of a flat mirror but with a different distance and size.)  This image may give the impression of being on the surface of the lens, but its image distance can be calculated if you know the curvature of the lens. (I can hold up my magnifying glass and get a nice reflected image of the scene outside my window.)

Answer (score 0):

Real images can not only be seen on a screen. If you place your eyes in the way of the light you can see the real image "in the air"
But since your ey adapts to the only object near by you seem to see it on the lens. If you place an empty frame where the screen should be placed your ey  may adapt to this frame and you see the real image in the frame, looking in the right direction.